# How to find disk IO in Mac OSX

Tags: macos, disk-io

I am using Mac 10.15.1

In Linux, we can read "diskstats" file in proc file system for this information.

I am able to find it using CoreFoundation and IOKit framework but is there anyway to read the Disk IO without using these frameworks ?

Comment: What's the objection to using the proper tools please?

Comment: Avoid using tool. It may possible that on another system, it may or may not be installed. So better to get from OS or kernel.

Comment: That is part of the OS on all Macs.